# Can I print Bangla in C++ or python ? what necessary steps should I take?

Tags: c++, python-3.x

Can I print Bangla in C++ or python ?  I tried using python but saw broken bangla texts . Again I tried in C++ , but it showed nothing. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkgdK.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQLbA.png)

So what necessary steps should I take to print bangla in console or powershell....?

Comment: The answer to "Can I?" is almost always yes, so focus on the "How can I?" side of the problem. If it turns out the answer is a rare "You can't", you'll get that for free from "How can I?"

Comment: `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);` from `<Windows.h>` combined with a UTF-8 string literal like `u8"ওহে বিশ্ব!"` might help.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can print Bangla text in both C++ and Python. However, to correctly display Bangla text, you need to make sure that your environment supports Unicode and the necessary fonts for Bangla characters.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Enable UTF-8 encoding

print("বাংলা ভাষা")
```

Make sure that your terminal or console supports UTF-8 encoding. If you are using a script file, ensure that you include the # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- comment at the beginning of the file.

**In C++**, you can use Unicode escape sequences to print Bangla text:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::wcout << L"বাংলা ভাষা" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In this C++ example, std::wcout is used for wide character output, and L is used to create wide string literals.

Again, make sure that your terminal or console supports Unicode, and you have a font that includes Bangla characters.

**Some Considerations:**

- **Text Editor/IDE Encoding**: Ensure that the text editor or IDE you are
  using supports UTF-8 encoding.
- **Console/Shell Encoding**: Make sure that your terminal or console
  supports UTF-8 encoding. Some terminals might need explicit
  configuration for Unicode support.
- **Font**: Ensure that your system has a font that includes Bangla
  characters.